# How Identify android application to asp.net?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I have an android application and I have a Visual Studio project that use by asp.net . I send HTTP Request from android app to asp.net. I have problem, everybody can see my data by search my website address and everybody can change my data. So this web service haven't security.
Please help me secure my web service.

Comment: A good start would be to look up token based authentication. JWT could be an option. Then you have to make sure that the user on the app end sends the token each request. You gave us no details what so ever, so I am just going to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jakobmillah mentioned JWT could be a good start.

https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core helped me getting into it, but i don`t know about the android part.

But the basic idea is to retrieve the token from the asp.net application by sending a username and a password. When the login was successfull you will get a response back with a token. Store that token somewhere in your android application. You will send this token on every request from your android app to your web application in the Authroization header and you are good to go